# Unable to load class (Old java cellphone game)

Tags: java, java-me

I've got an old, forgotten, java game for the old Siemens cellphones that I would like to play again. But I don't have a phone anymore. So I've been trying to emulate it. But it's not working.

Kemulator drops this error:

> KEmulator v1.0.0 Running...
>   Launch MIDlet class: Incubus
>   Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/siemens/mp/ga
>   me/GraphicObject
>       at Incubus.startApp(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet.invokeStartApp(Unknown Source)
>       at emulator.c.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Could there be some way to fix or bypass this?

Update: 
I've installed the SMTK Core Pack 0.11.1.49 and the M55 SMTK Emulator Pack V0.9.00.1 (From Siemens). I thought that should fix this problem with the J2ME Siemens Java API. But it hangs the emulator with this error:

> Called memory allocator when forbidden

Comment: Would it be too much effort to implement your own com.siemens.mp.game package?

Answer (score 1):

The game is using the J2ME Siemens Java API (from Siemens SMTK) which is platform dependent, the emulator can't handle those Siemens specific calls.

Maybe there's a library which converts those Siemens calls to generic J2ME or something, but probably not.